# If $\neg p \Leftrightarrow\neg q $ does that mean that $ p \Leftrightarrow q $

Tags: logic

Is showing  $\neg p \Leftrightarrow\neg q $ a valid proof of  $ p \Leftrightarrow q $ , why? An example would help.

I dont know much about logic so a  pdf book refernce could also help

Comment: Yes. Try applying the contrapositive.

Comment: yes, because equivalence returns true when both values are the same. and if $\neg p = \neg q$ then $p=q$

Comment: @Kaynex i dont know what  a contrapositive is

Comment: $ p \Leftrightarrow q$ means : they are both true or both false. Thus, adding negation to both, you swap the two cases and the result will be : $ \lnot p \Leftrightarrow \lnot q$ that means : they are both false or both true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That isnt what i wanted to ask i am sorry if i phrased it wrong. When writing p⇔q i mean two statements are equivalent, not just their truth values, but completely equivalent

Comment: Example: John is a teenager $\iff$ John is between $13$ and $19$. John is not between $13$ and $19$ $\iff$ John is not a teenager.

Comment: @farruhota i was looking for something more formal

Comment: @MilanStojanovic: use truth tables if you want formal proof that two expressions produce the same results

Comment: What does "not just having the same truth values, but completely equivalent" mean here? This is something you need to explain, otherwise we don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: But [logical equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) means exactly : "they have the same truth value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal proof:
$(p \leftrightarrow q) \equiv (p \to q) \wedge (q \to p)\equiv (\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg q \lor p) $

$(\neg p \leftrightarrow \neg q) \equiv (\neg p \to \neg q) \wedge (\neg q \to \neg p)\equiv (p \lor \neg q) \land (q \lor \neg p) $ (which is the same as above)

Comment: currently i dont have enough knowledge to understand this

Comment: @MilanStojanovic: If this is the case, you may want to use the truth tables. If truth tables are the same, the expressions are equivalent.